# Creating a graph from a 2-d space populated with circles

Tags: graph, graphics, geometry, 2d, graph-algorithm

I'm populating a 2-D space with circles of random position and radius.

I also want to create a graph where every circle is a vertex and has edges to other intersecting circles.

My question is: **Is there an efficient way to create this kind of graph?**

Obviously theres the brute force method of just checking each circle. I also figured that I can maybe overlay a grid on the 2-D plane and sort-of hash the circles so I can easily find circles in a specific region.

Here's an example of what I am working with:

[image: Example]

Comment: A quadtree might be of use

Answer (score 0):

The example image suggests you might have an upper bound *R* on the radii of the circles which is considerably smaller than the total edge length of your rectangle. If that is the case, you might want to try the followung:

```
Sort all circles by x coordinate of center
Maintain a list L of circles, sorted by y coordinate of center, initially empty
For each circle C1 in order of x coordinates:
  Drop all elements C2 from L where x2 < x1 - 2*R (or x2 < x1 - r2 - R)
  For each circle C2 in L where |y1 - y2| < r1 + R:
    Check C1, C2 for intersection, possibly add to result
  Add C1 to L, maintaining order by y coordinates
```

`L` could be a red-black tree or something similar where executing a range query (namely `y1 - r1 - R < y2 < y1 + r1 + R`) is simple. But to efficiently remove elements when they fall out of range, you may need a second structure, most likely a stack (with the loose `- 2*R` limit) or a priority queue (with the tighter `- r2 - R` limit).

If *R* is close to the typical size of your circles, this should work well. If not, a quad tree might be better, where you'd only visit adjacent cells if you actually encounter a big circle, instead of wasting work just because there might be a biger circle yet to come.